# How to quit current state animation correctly?

Tags: unity, animation

I've a 'classic' humanoid player with an animation controller and some animations.

This is the code i'm managing state changin

```
        float h = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
        if (h < 0) {
            m_Animator.SetTrigger ("LeftWalking");
        }
        else if (h > 0) {
            m_Animator.SetTrigger ("RightWalking");
        }
        else if (m_CharacterController.velocity.magnitude != 0) {
            m_Animator.SetTrigger ("Walking");
        }
        else if (m_Jumping) {
            m_Animator.SetTrigger ("Jump");
        }
        else {
            m_Animator.SetTrigger ("Idle");
            m_Animator.ResetTrigger ("Walking");
            m_Animator.ResetTrigger ("LeftWalking");
            m_Animator.ResetTrigger ("RightWalking");
            m_Animator.ResetTrigger ("Jump");
        }
    }
```

My problem is that after i stop to press my "forward" button (that make my player walking), the walking animation continue to play itself till the end.

This is my state machine
[image]

This is options of Walking to Idle state

[image]

I'm pretty sure I've to "play" with HasExitTime and/or FixedDuration but i'm not sure...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the HasExitTime checkbox to allow the transition to trigger at anytime.

See the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Transition.html) about HasExitTime

Comment: In  your opinion is it also correct to manage state using Trigger variable instead Boolean ?

Answer (score 0):

As Basile already said, uncheck HasExitTime. You should also uncheck the fixed duration box and set the transition duration to 0. Good luck:)